# Expression or idiom that means "But you're doing the same"?

Tags: idiom-request

> "Are you threatening me?"
>
> "Right back at you!"

Now, that's not a good idiom, and I am not even sure if this is an appropriate response, so I am wondering if there's an idiom that basically means "You did it first, or you're doing or did the same thing". Is there such an expression?

Comment: What precise context do you need this expression for? Gary's answer below correctly answers your question, but it doesn't apply naturally to the sample conversation you provided because the first person asked a question. Although it's a rather accusatory question, it's not a statement, and "the pot calling the kettle black" only applies to direct accusations in statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Well, isn't that the pot calling the kettle black

The pot and the kettle have been in the same fire, blackened by the same soot, in the same way, and likely at the same time.  What's true of the accused kettle is also true of the accusing pot.

Answer (score 1):

You have specifically asked about a question rather than a statement, and this limits the number of replies. To me, the most natural reply is this:

> I might ask you the same thing!